# OR-Tools CP-SAT solver runs forever without finding a solution on large social golfer problem

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

I am using CP-SAT solver of OR Tools to solve the following problem: 190 people participate in a corporate event that lasts three days. Along these three days, people have eight meals that are served in a dinning room in which there are 19 tables with 10 chairs each. The objective is to assign the chairs to the people in such a way that, along the eight meals, any given person doesn’t seat more than once at the same table with any other person (i.e. any two people only coincide at most once on the same table). Besides this constraint, the code includes one more constraint consisting of the following: each one of the people with codes 1 to 19 must be seated at a different table.

The problem I'm having is that my Python code doesn't get a solution for the eight meals. The code I am using is derived from https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/wedding_optimal_chart_sat.py

I've used the code to solve the problem for five meals, and the code got a solution. Then I tried with six meals and then with seven meals and for these cases, the code got a solution in less than 5000 seconds. When I ran the code to get the solution for eight meals, the code got runninf forever without getting a solution and I stopped it when it had been runninf for more than 50 hours. The code didn't also established that the problem is infeasible. I expected CP-SAT to either solve the problem or say it is infeasible.

I’m using Python 3.12.0 64 bits.

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Copyright 2010-2022 Google LLC
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.


import time
from typing import Sequence
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model


class MesasMDChartPrinterWithLimit(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
    """Print intermediate solutions."""

    def __init__(self, seats, names, num_tables, num_guests, limit):
        cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        self.__solution_count = 0
        self.__solution_limit = limit
        self.__start_time = time.time()
        self.__seats = seats
        self.__names = names
        self.__num_tables = num_tables
        self.__num_guests = num_guests

    def on_solution_callback(self):
        current_time = time.time()
        objective = self.ObjectiveValue()
        print(
            "Solution %i, time = %f s, objective = %i"
            % (self.__solution_count, current_time - self.__start_time, objective)
        )
        self.__solution_count += 1

        for t in range(self.__num_tables):
            print("Table %d: " % t, end="")
            for g in range(self.__num_guests):
                if self.Value(self.__seats[(t, g)]):
                    print("  " + self.__names[g] + ",", end="")
            print("")
        print("")
        if self.__solution_count >= self.__solution_limit:
            print(f"Stop search after {self.__solution_limit} solutions")
            self.StopSearch()
            #return


    def num_solutions(self):
        return self.__solution_count


def build_data():
    """Build the data model."""

    num_tables = 152
    table_capacity = 10

    # Codes of the guests.

    names = [
        "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17",
        "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32",
        "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", 
        "48", "49", 
        "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", 
        "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", 
        "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", 
        "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", 
        "109", "110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", "121", 
        "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", 
        "135", "136", "137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", 
        "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155", "156", "157", "158", "159", "160", 
        "161", "162", "163", "164", "165", "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", "173", 
        "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", "182", "183", "184", "185", "186", 
        "187", "188", "189", "190",
    ]

    return num_tables, table_capacity, names


def solve_with_discrete_model():
    """Discrete approach."""
    num_tables, table_capacity, names = build_data()

    num_guests = 190

    all_tables = range(num_tables)
    all_guests = range(num_guests)

    num_tables_first_meal = int(num_tables/8)

    all_tables_first_meal = range(num_tables_first_meal)
    all_tables_second_meal = range(num_tables_first_meal, num_tables_first_meal * 2)
    all_tables_third_meal = range(num_tables_first_meal * 2, num_tables_first_meal * 3)
    all_tables_fourth_meal = range(num_tables_first_meal * 3, num_tables_first_meal * 4)
    all_tables_fifth_meal = range(num_tables_first_meal * 4, num_tables_first_meal * 5)
    all_tables_sixth_meal = range(num_tables_first_meal * 5, num_tables_first_meal * 6)
    all_tables_seventh_meal = range(num_tables_first_meal * 6, num_tables_first_meal * 7)
    all_tables_eighth_meal = range(num_tables_first_meal * 7, num_tables)


    # Create the cp model.
    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    #
    # Decision variables
    #
    seats = {}
    for t in all_tables:
        for g in all_guests:
            seats[(t, g)] = model.NewBoolVar("guest %i seats on table %i" % (g, t))

    colocated = {}
    for g1 in range(num_guests - 1):
        for g2 in range(g1 + 1, num_guests):
            colocated[(g1, g2)] = model.NewBoolVar(
                "guest %i seats with guest %i" % (g1, g2)
            )

    same_table = {}
    for g1 in range(num_guests - 1):
        for g2 in range(g1 + 1, num_guests):
            for t in all_tables:
                same_table[(g1, g2, t)] = model.NewBoolVar(
                    "guest %i seats with guest %i on table %i" % (g1, g2, t)
                )

    #
    # Constraints
    #

    for g in all_guests:
        model.Add(sum(seats[(t, g)] for t in all_tables_first_meal) == 1)
    for g in all_guests:
        model.Add(sum(seats[(t, g)] for t in all_tables_second_meal) == 1)
    for g in all_guests:
        model.Add(sum(seats[(t, g)] for t in all_tables_third_meal) == 1)
    for g in all_guests:
        model.Add(sum(seats[(t, g)] for t in all_tables_fourth_meal) == 1)
    for g in all_guests:
        model.Add(sum(seats[(t, g)] for t in all_tables_fifth_meal) == 1)
    for g in all_guests:
        model.Add(sum(seats[(t, g)] for t in all_tables_sixth_meal) == 1)
    for g in all_guests:
        model.Add(sum(seats[(t, g)] for t in all_tables_seventh_meal) == 1)
    for g in all_guests:
        model.Add(sum(seats[(t, g)] for t in all_tables_eighth_meal) == 1)

    # Tables have a max capacity.
    for t in all_tables:
        model.Add(sum(seats[(t, g)] for g in all_guests) <= table_capacity)

    # Link colocated with seats
    for g1 in range(num_guests - 1):
        for g2 in range(g1 + 1, num_guests):
            for t in all_tables:
                # Link same_table and seats.
                model.AddBoolOr(
                    [
                        seats[(t, g1)].Not(),
                        seats[(t, g2)].Not(),
                        same_table[(g1, g2, t)],
                    ]
                )
                model.AddImplication(same_table[(g1, g2, t)], seats[(t, g1)])
                model.AddImplication(same_table[(g1, g2, t)], seats[(t, g2)])

            # Link colocated and same_table.
            model.Add(
                sum(same_table[(g1, g2, t)] for t in all_tables) == colocated[(g1, g2)]
            )


    # Symmetry breaking.

    model.Add(seats[(0, 0)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(1, 1)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(2, 2)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(3, 3)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(4, 4)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(5, 5)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(6, 6)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(7, 7)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(8, 8)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(9, 9)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(10, 10)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(11, 11)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(12, 12)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(13, 13)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(14, 14)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(15, 15)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(16, 16)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(17, 17)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(18, 18)] == 1)
 
    model.Add(seats[(19, 0)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(20, 1)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(21, 2)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(22, 3)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(23, 4)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(24, 5)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(25, 6)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(26, 7)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(27, 8)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(28, 9)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(29, 10)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(30, 11)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(31, 12)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(32, 13)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(33, 14)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(34, 15)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(35, 16)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(36, 17)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(37, 18)] == 1)
 
    model.Add(seats[(38, 0)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(39, 1)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(40, 2)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(41, 3)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(42, 4)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(43, 5)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(44, 6)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(45, 7)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(46, 8)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(47, 9)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(48, 10)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(49, 11)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(50, 12)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(51, 13)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(52, 14)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(53, 15)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(54, 16)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(55, 17)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(56, 18)] == 1)
 
    model.Add(seats[(57, 0)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(58, 1)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(59, 2)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(60, 3)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(61, 4)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(62, 5)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(63, 6)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(64, 7)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(65, 8)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(66, 9)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(67, 10)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(68, 11)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(69, 12)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(70, 13)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(71, 14)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(72, 15)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(73, 16)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(74, 17)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(75, 18)] == 1)
 
    model.Add(seats[(76, 0)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(77, 1)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(78, 2)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(79, 3)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(80, 4)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(81, 5)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(82, 6)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(83, 7)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(84, 8)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(85, 9)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(86, 10)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(87, 11)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(88, 12)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(89, 13)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(90, 14)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(91, 15)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(92, 16)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(93, 17)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(94, 18)] == 1)
 
    model.Add(seats[(95, 0)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(96, 1)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(97, 2)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(98, 3)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(99, 4)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(100, 5)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(101, 6)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(102, 7)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(103, 8)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(104, 9)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(105, 10)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(106, 11)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(107, 12)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(108, 13)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(109, 14)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(110, 15)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(111, 16)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(112, 17)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(113, 18)] == 1)
 
    model.Add(seats[(114, 0)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(115, 1)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(116, 2)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(117, 3)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(118, 4)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(119, 5)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(120, 6)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(121, 7)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(122, 8)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(123, 9)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(124, 10)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(125, 11)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(126, 12)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(127, 13)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(128, 14)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(129, 15)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(130, 16)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(131, 17)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(132, 18)] == 1)
 
    model.Add(seats[(133, 0)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(134, 1)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(135, 2)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(136, 3)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(137, 4)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(138, 5)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(139, 6)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(140, 7)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(141, 8)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(142, 9)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(143, 10)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(144, 11)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(145, 12)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(146, 13)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(147, 14)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(148, 15)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(149, 16)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(150, 17)] == 1)
    model.Add(seats[(151, 18)] == 1)
 


    ### Solve model.
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    solver.parameters.linearization_level = 0
    solver.parameters.enumerate_all_solutions = False
    solver.parameters.stop_after_first_solution = True
    solution_limit = 1
    solution_printer = MesasMDChartPrinterWithLimit(seats, names, num_tables, num_guests,  solution_limit)

    solver.Solve(model, solution_printer)


    print("Statistics")
    print("  - conflicts    : %i" % solver.NumConflicts())
    print("  - branches     : %i" % solver.NumBranches())
    print("  - wall time    : %f s" % solver.WallTime())
    print("  - num solutions: %i" % solution_printer.num_solutions())



def main(argv: Sequence[str]) -> None:
    solve_with_discrete_model()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main("")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you expect the model:

```
#Variables: 2'775'995
  - 2'775'995 Booleans in [0,1]
#kBoolOr: 8'187'480 (#enforced: 5'458'320) (#literals: 13'645'800)
#kLinear1: 152
#kLinearN: 19'627 (#terms: 2'804'875)
```

to be solved trivially with 1 worker?

This is ambitious.

Can you check the model is as small as possible ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Laurent, for your comments. I am new with this technology and I don't know how to get the model smaller. I also don't understand what you say about "1 worker" because the log search progress says "Setting number of workers to 12". Are these 12 workers different workers from the one you are referring to?

Comment: Bibd or social golfers problems are extremely hard to solve with plenty of symmetries. Your problem is huge by or standards, and is exponential in nature.

Comment: I've run the code for six and seven meals, with solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True, and the data I get, are:

Comment: I've run the code for six and seven meals, with solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True, and the data I get, are the following. For 6 meals, 2'086'485 variables and 1038 seconds spent to get a solution. For 7 meals, 2'431'240 variables and 3426 seconds spent to get a solution. Since for 8 meals there are 2'775'995 variables and CP-SAT couldn't find a solution during 180000 seconds. Is the exponential nature of this problem the cause that 180000 seconds are not enough to find the solution? The increase of the number of variables from 7 to 8 meals is 14%